# $\omega +1 $ is not isomorphic to $\omega$ (in the well-ordering by $\varepsilon$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- $\omega +1 $ is not isomorphic to $\omega$ (in the well-ordering by $\varepsilon$).

I see that $\omega +1$ does have maximal element but $\omega$ is not so there is no ismorphism between $\omega +1 $ and $\omega $ but how can I write as proof this?

Comment: What do you mean how do you write a proof? This pretty much is a proof. An isomorphism takes a maximal element to a maximal element. There is nothing to take $\omega$ to, so there is no isomorphism.

Comment: @tomasz Yes but is this a mathematically proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically proof"? In the sense of proof theory, not at all, but no one actually writes proofs that way. In the sense that it is a completely clear and sound reasoning, at least to me, yes. If it does not convince you, you should clarify your question with your doubts.

Comment: @tomasz okey, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is how you might translate your reasoning into a slightly more formal proof.

> Suppose towards contradiction that $\varphi\colon \omega+1\to \omega$ is an isomorphism. Notice that $\omega\in \omega+1$ is a maximal element.
>
> Since order isomorphisms map maximal elements to maximal elements, it follows that $\varphi(\omega)$ is maximal in $\omega$. But $\omega$ has no maximal element, a contradiction, which finishes the proof.

As suggested by Henno Brandsma in the comments, this proof presupposes that we already know that being a maximal element is preserved by order isomorphism. If that is not completely clear, the proof of this fact should be included.

Comment: Maybe the OP needs to prove the lemma that an order isomorphism maps maximal elements to maximal elements as well. Or it might have been proved before, it depends on how much his course covered so far and how formal his/her proofs are expected to be.